# Unity ScrollRect doesn't scroll

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

So I am trying to make a dynamic text area, scrollable with a scrollbar, using ScrollRect. Scrollbar, text container (ScrollRect), and text with content are stored in the output panel on the same level.
[Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMxMc.png)
[TextContainer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eNrc.png)
But for some reason, the scrollbar size is automatically set to 1 and everything scrolls only by a pair of pixels. Drag scrolling doesn't work at all, same with mouse wheel.
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd3NK.png)

I read docs, searched for similar problem, and experimented, but the problem persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the viewport variable for anything regarding the scroll view to function. I'd say you're better off creating a new Scroll View in the hierarchy and observing its structure, then copying it over to your current hierarchy -- or, if possible, include the text fields directly on the newly-created Scroll View.

Your Scroll Rect component should look somewhat like this:
[image: Your component should look like this]

For Scroll Sensitivity, play around with values between 40-90 to find the one that suits you. I prefer to use 70.